# Using UITable to display data but showing error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sigabrt

I am trying to setup a roster page for my `iOS` app to show a list of data. When ever I go to show data, I am getting an `NSException` and signal `SIGABRT`

I have tried to look stuff up and found nothing on how to fix this error with the `UITable`. I have the UITable linked to the item as well

```swift
    let list = ["Driver 1 ", "Driver 2"]

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return(list.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return(cell)
    }
```

What I am expecting is to show the data and display like my android app to where the table can be switched around. and also have 3 row showng the drivers number team owner and the driver. But I am getting these errors.

Comment: "I have tried to look stuff up and found nothing on how to fix this error with the UITable". Then I don't think you've looked very hard. Research `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "...", for: indexPath)`

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the crash? What is the completion error message? Please [edit[ your question with all of these details.

Comment: I suggest you go through the developer documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html). This will give you a better understanding of `UITableView`s. It also has sample code. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unrelated but `return` is not a function. Remove the parentheses for example `return cell`

Comment: @rmaddy I am not getting any syntax error what so ever besides on startup it opens the launch screen then gives me a “Signal SIGABRT” as well as a NSException

Comment: @XxModZxXWiiPlaza Right. And that crashed is being caused by one specific line of code. You need to tell us which line that is. And you need to copy and paste the entire error message from Xcode console that is shown when the app crashes.

Comment: @rmaddy  Unknown class _TtC19FirstViewController8Homepage in Interface Builder file. -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103315a20
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103315a20'
(lldb)

Comment: [Edit] your question. Do not post relevant details in comments. No one will see them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-using the cell like this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : UITableViewCell!
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    if cell == nil 
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return(cell)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a new `UITableViewCell` yourself, like you did here

`let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")`

Just let the `tableView` create a cell for you. Your code should look  like this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```